# Dormir « à la fraîche », locution adverbiale employée pour désigner non pas un moment particulier mais « au frais/à l'air frais » dans une pièce ?

Tags: sens, adverbes, locutions

J'ai expliqué à quelqu'un que j'aimais garder la fenêtre un peu ouverte quand je dors, même l'hiver, pour avoir de l'air et parce que je n'aime pas avoir trop chaud et que j'aime entendre le bruit des vagues ([Bas du Fleuve](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bas-Saint-Laurent)) et on m'a répondu que j'aimais dormir « [à la fraîche](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/frais_1#e5a6c33f72fab56d) », en locution adverbiale. Mais ce n'était pas pour signifier un moment particulier de la nuit mais pour dire « [au frais](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/frais_1#b7c1d9b6ad06bdc2) » ou « à l'air frais ».

Est-on familier avec ce sens particulier de la locution ? Y a-t-il une nuance de sens ou autrement entre « à la fraîche », « au frais » et « à l'air frais » dans ce contexte ; lequel trouve-t-on le plus usuel dans ce contexte ?

Answer (score 5):

***Au frais*** ou ***à l'air frais*** n'informe que de la température plus basse que la normale. C'est peut-être l'air conditionné ou une absence de chauffage qui en sont la raison.

***À la fraîche***, en plus de la fraicheur de l'air, implique que cet air est naturellement frais, que c'est l'air ambiant de l'extérieur où il fait nuit.

***Dormir à la fraîche*** signifie pour moi dormir à la belle étoile. Dans ton cas, ç'aurait donc été au sens figuré ou une exagération humoristique.

***Partir à la fraîche***, plus courant, signifie partir au petit matin, avant que le soleil ne se soit levé, avant qu'il ait réchauffé l'atmosphère.

Comment: Hum… Oulipo dixit : relire la définition de *frai*, de *frais* et de fra**î**che  et trouver ou imaginer celle de fra**i**che … *frisquet* ce programme !

Comment: @Personne Oups, j'avais oublié de mettre un chapeau... À ma décharge, c'est officiellement [permis](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9F1500?history=0) depuis 1990

Comment: … jeune homme, l'excuse est acceptée :-) … mais votre vision du passage oulipiesque de **frai** à **frai**che est attendue ::--))

Comment: @Personne *Jeune*, c'est vite dit mais les poissons fraient-ils à la fraîche ?

Comment: … ou alors *encore jeune homme* qui attend sa retraite et s'interroge sur la question fondamentale de l'onanisme piscicole : « Les fraîches poissonnes débutantes palpent-elles la fraiche du frai ou de la fraîche d'un frai fait à la fraîche ? » -— Brisons là, sinon les censeurs vont nous la faire Cosette.